# Angularjs - Angular UI $modal and $modalInstance within one controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I would like to ask, I understand that AngularUI's modal consist of 2 controllers 1 is the default controller that I use to process data and the other one is to handle $modelInstances, which is fine for me. But what I wanted to do is I have several scopes that I will be using while rendering/editing data in my modal display. Instead of resolving all these scope between controllers what i tried to do is to merge both controllers together so the scopes can be shared among the webpages. (Noted that its a realtime scope) What I did is like below

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('app').controller('ModelCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $modalInstance) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  //I have a few more scopes to be used in the model

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: true,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModelCtrl',
      size: 'lg',
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function () {

    }, function () {

    });
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

I've combined both controller into one, and inject the relevant modules back so it would work, theoretically. But instead what I've got is an error saying `[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance <- ModelCtrl`. Understand from this error which mean I have injected an unknown provider `$modalInstanceProvider` so I've tried to remove the $modalInstance from the modules, the Modal managed to open but the the action for `close` and `dismiss` throws me an error of `$modalInstance is not defined`. What have i done wrong and how should i combine both controllers instead of separating them into 2?

here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7jpKT99UksJ7dbHhgpDp) link so you can understand what i mean. thank you.

Comment: i hope this will not work, i dislike modal popup angularjs

Comment: No, you not able to use `$model` and `$modalInstance` in same controller.

Comment: @gauravbhavsar any alternative to this?

Comment: Hi, not sure that you should actually combine the two controllers.... both have different purposes... the most clean way to do this would be parent controller a service or factory that handles the modals settings and a modal controller... this is how I do it... and then you can always pass the data you want... if you want Ill give you an  example

Comment: @Jony-Y Thank you for your advise and yes i acknowledge such approach and I've alter my code to work in such a way.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create a new controller for created modal
just do this:

`angular.module('app').controller('ModelCtrl', function ($scope, $modal) {`

see that i didn't inject `$modalInstance`

then modal creation be like:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  animation: true,
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  size: 'lg',
  scope: $scope, //i make modal scope the same as  ModelCtrl scope
});
```

then you use `modalInstance` that you created to manipulate the modal

so final code is

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('app').controller('ModelCtrl', function ($scope, $modal) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  //I have a few more scopes to be used in the model

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: true,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      size: 'lg',
      scope: $scope
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function () {

    }, function () {

    });
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked above answer, but modalInstance close was not working. So changed code like below, its working now.

```
$scope.open = function() {
$scope.$modalInstance = $modal.open({
    scope: $scope,
    templateUrl: "modalContent.html",
    size: '',
}
};

$scope.ok = function() {
    $scope.$modalInstance.close();
};

$scope.cancel = function() {
    $scope.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```